# How do I sum the first two values in each tuple in a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I searched through stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer or adapt similar codes, unfortunately.
The problem is that I have a list of tuples:

```
tupl = [(5,3,33), (2,5,2), (4,1,7)]
```

and I should use list comprehension to have this output:

```
[8,7,5]
```

The code that I wrote is a bit dump and is:

```
sum_tupl = []
tupl = [(5,3,33), (2,5,2), (4,1,7)]
sum_tupl = [tupl[0][0]+tupl[0][1] for tuple in tupl]
sum_tupl
```

but instead of doing what I want it to do, it returns

```
[8,8,8]
```

which is the sum of the first couple executed three times.
I tried using a variant:

```
tupl = [(5,3,33), (2,5,2), (4,1,7)]
sum_tupl = [sum(tupl[0],tupl[1]) for tuple in tupl]
sum_tupl
```

(which is missing something) but to no avail.

Comment: `[sum(t[0:2]) for t in tupl]`

Answer (score 1):

Note: When you're beginning python, it's much easier to use loops instead of list comprehensions because then you can *[debug](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)* your code more easily, either by using `print()` statements or by stepping through it using a [debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953).

---

Now, on to the answer:

When you do `for x in y`, with a list `y`, the *individual items* go in `x`. So for your code `for tuple in tupl`, you shouldn't use `tupl` because that is the *entire list*. You need to use the *individual item in the list*, i.e. `tuple`.

Note that it's not a good idea to name a variable `tuple` because that's already a builtin type in python.

You need:

```
tupl = [(5,3,33), (2,5,2), (4,1,7)]
sum_tupl = [t[0]+t[1] for t in tupl]
```

Which gives the list

```
sum_tupl: [8, 7, 5]
```

If you have more elements you want to sum, it makes more sense to use the `sum()` function and a slice of `t` instead of writing out everything. For example, if you wanted to sum the first 5 elements, you'd write

```
sum_tupl = [sum(t[0:5]) for t in tupl]
```

instead of

```
sum_tupl = [t[0]+t[1]+t[2]+t[3]+t[4] for t in tupl]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I did a really stupid mistake. Also thanks for the tip about calling variables in a different way, I usually do it but I think I shuold just stop it before it's too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Each loop iteration you're accessing the first element of your `tupl` list, instead of using the current element. This is what you want:

```
sum_tupl = [t[0] + t[1] for t in tupl]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer slicing:

```
>>> [x + y for x, y, *_ in tupl]
[8, 7, 5]
>>>
```